# PHP Telegram Inline-Button with different Text and Command

Tags: php, telegram

I have created some Telegram inline buttons with a `for` loop.

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 35; $i++) {
    $arr[] = array(array(
        "text"          => $i,
        "callback_data" => "Test_".$i,
    ));
}
$bot->sendKeyboard($chat_id, $reply, $arr);

public function sendKeyboard($chat_id, $text, $keyboard = Array())
{
    $action = 'sendMessage';
    $param = array(
        'chat_id'       => $chat_id,
        'reply_markup'  => json_encode(array("keyboard" => $keyboard, "one_time_keyboard" => true, "resize_keyboard" => true)),
        'text'          => $text
    );
    
    $res = $this->send($action, $param);
    if (!$res['ok']) {
        $result = Array("success" => 0, "info"  =>  "Error: " . $res['description']);
            } else {
        $result = Array("success" => 1, "info"  =>  "Keyboard show");
            }
    return $result;
}
```

E.g. the Button-Text is 6, I want Telegram to write `Test_6` in chat.

What do I have to change so that a different text than that on the button is output?

Answer (score 0):

The `text` on a button is what the user sees in Telegram.

The `callback_data` is an internal value that you get back when somebody presses on the button, so you use that to handle the click event.

---

You'll need to create the buttons like so:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 35; $i++) {
    $arr[] = array(array(
        "text"          => "Test_".$i,
        "callback_data" => $i
    ));
}
```

So that the users sees `Test_1` until `Test_35`. And if somebody presses the button, you will get the number as data `1` to `35`.

Comment: OK and how can I evaluate the callback_data?

Comment: Depends on how you receive updates from Telegram. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60831910/how-to-get-callback-data-from-telegram-in-php) might help.

Comment: OK thanks, that works so far.
Please help me, is it possible to generate a keyboard in a loop?
Something like...

for ($i = 1; $i < 35; $i++) {
 $keyboard = json_encode([
  "inline_keyboard" => [
   [
    [
     "text"          => "Test_".$i,
     "callback_data" => $i
    ]
   ]
  ]
 ]);
}